# Как осуществляется доступ к полям вложенной структуры и как правильно освободить память?

Tags: структуры, c++

Есть две структуры одна вложенная в другую, причём вложенная - динамическая. Как осуществляется доступ к полям вложенной структуры (там указатель) и как правильно освободить память?

```
struct One {
    G4double A, B;
    G4int id;
};

struct Two {
    G4int event,part;
    struct One *Spin=new One[part];
} TwoInc;
```

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что это компилируется?
2. Если это C++, почему структуры, а не классы?
3. Освобождает память её владелец. Если структура `Two` — владелец экземпляра `One`, она ответственна за освобождение памяти. Когда именно «правильно» освободить память, должен знать лучше всего архитектор проекта, то есть вы. Часто это делается в деструкторе.

Comment: я Вам скажу больше, это ещё и корректно работает, правда не могу сосласться на указатель что бы освободить память...

Comment: не классы потому, что это уже в классе.

Comment: @glebasta:

1. Странно, у меня не компилируется: http://ideone.com/nVzVlF
2. То, что это «в классе», не проблема.

Comment: Ялибо разберусь с вектором, либо найду выход. Вот скомпилированная http://ideone.com/ufsrrx

Comment: @glebasta: Ну что ж, удачи вам. Пойду подучу C++.

Answer (score 3):

[[@glebasta](/users/20466/glebasta)](/users/20466/glebasta), не знаю, зачем понадобилось так сложно (и куда это вставить, чтобы откомпилировалось), но

```
 delete [] TwoInc.Spin;  // delete [] p->Spin; для Two *p;
```

должно работать.

А почему бы не вообще делать проще?

```
 struct Two { int event,part; struct One *Spin; };
 ...
 struct Two  TwoInc; 
 TwoInc.part = 10; // инициализируете нужным значением
 TwoInc.Spin = new One[TwoInc.part];
```

или в функции

```
 struct Two *ini_foo (struct Two *p, int inival) {
    p->part = inival;
    p->Spin = new One[inival];
    return p;
 }
```

просто и  понятно.

Comment: Вот это другое дело, завтра уже попробую. Дело в том, что это дата минин, есть события которые представлены определённым форматом и вот хотелось бы всё красиво пособытийно обработать. Появилась идея. Однако только такая. Вот так же осободал через делете... наверное дамп в другом месте вылетает. Первый вариант я пробовал, только извращённей, мб такой прокатит лучше. А вот 2й вариант интересен больше. Спасибо большое !!

Comment: Спасибо (я всё делал правильно). Оказывается дамп был в другом месте. Но вы натолкнули меня на мысль о том, как улучшить код. !! Честь и хвала ! :D